# How can i get rid of the circle in the branch in sourcetree?

Tags: branch, atlassian-sourcetree, pull

I have a problem with pull the branch, and I think it's related to circle in front of another branch (highlighted by an arrow) and i don't know how to rid of. If I want remote branch to pull: feature, only option is pull into local branch: Errors.

[image: screenshot of sourcetree]

Comment: I think the circle just means that's the branch currently checked out.